# Merge two collections in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have `IEnumerable<GroupResult<T>>` where `GroupResult<T>` is following:

```
public class GroupResult<T>
{
 public string Key { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

So let's say the collection looks like this:

```
{
Key: "1",
Items: { "A", "B" }
}

{
Key: "1",
Items: { "C", "D" }
}

{
Key: "2",
Items: { "E", "F" }
}
```

What operation can I perform to get the following:

```
{
Key: "1",
Items: { "A", "B", "C", "D" }
}

{
Key: "2",
Items: { "E", "F" }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Instead of using `IEnumerable<GroupResult<T>>`, you could use `Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<T>>` instead, which would prevent duplicate keys in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

use `GroupBy()`

```
var result = intput.GroupBy(x => x.Key)
                   .Select(x => new GroupResult() 
                          { 
                              Key = x.Key, 
                              Items = x.SelectMany(y => y.Items) 
                           });
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/p8HklJ

Comment: Unfortunately that does not change anything: https://imgur.com/a/l9PS7EG - ToString as seen in debugger is defined as: Key {Count}. Each GroupResult has 1 item, even those having the same Key.

Comment: @n0e https://dotnetfiddle.net/p8HklJ